# Check if string has same characters in a row

Tags: regex, scala

I need to find if there are dots in the string in a row.
For example

```
df...fd
```

This is not valid. 
But this

```
d.f.d.d
```

Is.
I am not so strong with regulars expression, does anyone has an idea how to do this? In scala.

Comment: you may use "df...fd".contains("..") prints true , "d.f.d.d"contains("..") prints false.

Answer (score 3):

A general-purpose solution that works not only on Strings, but on other collection types, is to use the `sliding` method. It basically slides a fixed-size window over the collection, returning an iterator of those windows.

```
// string example
val s = "df..fd"
s.sliding(2) contains ".."

// list example
val list = List(1,2,3,4,5,6,2,3,7)
list.sliding(3) contains List(6,2,3)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd say `contains` is really the best way to check something like 2 consecutive known characters. If you insist on a regex, here is a [sample code](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_scala_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMZFpPRVZjQ1JRc3c) (remember that you need to double-escape the dot to match a literal dot):

```
  val pattern = "\\.{2}".r
  val str = "df..d"
  println(pattern findFirstIn str)

  val pattern2 = "\\.{2}".r
  val str2 = "df.f.d"
  println(pattern2 findFirstIn str2)

  println("df...fd - Офелия".contains("..")) 
  println("df.f.fd - Офелия".contains(".."))
```

Output:

```
Some(..)                                                                                                                                                            
None                                                                                                                                                                
true                                                                                                                                                                
false
```

Comment: agree, a regex is not needed if only interested in a specific character. regex would be useful otherwise via capture group and backreference.